# How to convert images to gif using gif.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gif, animated-gif

So I'm using this library https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js

However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to convert images that I have into a gif. I've tried doing two things

First approach -
 In the function that takes the image (called a number of times)

```
var newWebCamImage = new webcamImageView({imageUri: imageUri});
$("body").find(".webcam-images").append(newWebCamImage.render().$el);
```

This function is passed to setInterval, so from that function I call

```
createGif: function() {
    var webcamImages = this.$el.find(".webcam-image");
    for(var i = 0; i < webcamImages.length; i ++){
        this.gif.addFrame(webcamImage[i]);
    }
    this.gif.render();
},
```

This doesn't do anything - the library doc doesn't tell me where the gif will appear, or to what element I should append it to.

The second approach -

In the function in `setInterval`-

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = imageUri;
that.gif.addFrame(image);
```

I then call `gif.render()` elsewhere, once I have all of the images.

This doesn't do anything because I haven't appended the gif to the DOM anywhere.

How am I supposed to use this library?